# Import of an attribute of a python module fails

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have the following directory structure:

http://localhost:8888/notebooks/translation.ipynb
http://localhost:8888/edit/Fill_temp/prepare_test_data.py

In

> prepare_test_data.py

I have a function:

```
def to_cap (EXP_FILE, SAMPLES_FILE: str= EXP_FILE + '.cap', cap_rate=0, by_token=False):
```

In the notebook

> translation.ipynb

I do these imports:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import Fill_temp
import Fill_temp.prepare_test_data
```

then I run

```
Fill_temp.prepare_test_data.to_cap("en12.json.pres", "en12.cap.0")
```

and I get

```
AttributeError: module 'Fill_temp.prepare_test_data' has no attribute 'to_cap'
```

How come?

I explicitly imported both the Fill_temp package and the prepare_test_data module.

Do I need to import even the lowest level functions that are defined in the module?

EDIT:

I tried to import the low level function explicitly:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import Fill_temp
import Fill_temp.prepare_test_data
import Fill_temp.prepare_test_data.to_cap
```

but I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'Fill_temp.prepare_test_data.to_cap';
>   'Fill_temp.prepare_test_data' is not a package

So what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit bizarre. Basically, it turned out that there was a syntax error in that low level function.

But instead of saying it jupyter was saying that it doesn't see that function. Which is a really counter-intuitive error message.